# ClassCastException at Gallery.setLayoutParams?

Tags: android

I am create a base adapter for a Gallery.

I am using this method to override getView().

But i keep getting this error at the LayoutParam's code.

```
10-02 01:14:32.543: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-02 01:14:32.543: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Gallery$LayoutParams
10-02 01:14:32.543: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:659)
10-02 01:14:32.543: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:311)
10-02 01:14:32.543: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
10-02 01:14:32.543: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChild(ViewGroup.java:3109)
```

Here is my method..

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lazyitemt, null);


    ImageView image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image);
    image.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(250, 250));
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(data[position], activity, image);
    return vi;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the view child with id `image` inside of a `Gallery`? According to the stack trace, it looks like the child is trying to be positioned by a `LinearLayout`, which can not use the `Gallery.LayoutParams` params. Are you sure that there's only one `View` in your layout that is identified by id `image`, and are you sure that this view is not getting somehow moved from a `Gallery` into a `LinearLayout`?

Comment: As a side note: if you didn't already do this, try cleaning your project and rebuilding it from scratch. I've found that sometimes the resources file can get out of sync with reality, which leads to strange `ClassCastException`s during layout, since the actual ID values point to unexpected layout elements.

Comment: Now i get a NullPointer exception where i set the LayoutParam's. I changed the ImageView's ID.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post some more code. In particular, the .xml layout file, and the rest of your Gallery class and the corresponding activity.